# Existence $a,b,c \in R$ such that $\det(aA+bB+cC)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A,B,C \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $AB=BA, AC=CA, BC=CB$. Prove that, there exists $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}, a^2+b^2+c^2 \not=0$ such that $\det(aA+bB+cC)=0$?

This is my exercise, but i just have solution for $n$ is odd :(

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.** Commuting real matrices are simultaneously triangularisable over $\mathbb C$. Suppose they are all upper triangular. It suffices to show that for some real numbers $a,b,c$, some diagonal element of $aA+bB+cC$ is zero. Now, given any three arbitrary but fixed complex numbers $u,v,w$, by considering the real part and imaginary part of the equation $au+bv+cw=0$, you get two equations and three unknowns.